# delete rows and change pagination counters?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want change `1 تا 6 از 36`=translator to EN=> `1 to 6 of 36` after delete row(s)(with click on link **DELETE**) in table.
**EXAMPLE:** total rows is `36` if we delete `3` rows, this total row online change to `33` (like when that select value of select box and change this part of table).

You see this link that be clear: http://binboy.gigfa.com/admin/accommodation/show 
Here is my full js code: http://binboy.gigfa.com/files/js/admin.js

With respect

Comment: -1 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?

Comment: please post the relevant code its very difficult to go through all of your code and then find the actual problem, only post the part where you are having problems **P.S: the -1 is not from me**

Comment: @KateThompson: Indeed, that's from me. I also voted to close this question. You're not asking about a *specific* programming thing that confuses you, you're asking (broadly) how to add a feature to your code, without telling us anything that you've tried or even isolating the relevant code. We're not here to do your work for you, particularly when you aren't showing any effort to have solved the problem yourself. This was discussed in the comments to your previous question. Also, this question can't stand alone in the future, but relies entirely on your links which are probably not stable.

Answer (score 0):

this is not specifically related to your problem since you were not very clear however below is the solution that depicts what you need

```
<div id="score">
    <span id="upper">1</span>
    <span id="to">to</span>
    <span id="lower">3</span>
</div>
<div id="chk">
    <input type="checkbox"  /><br/>
    <input type="checkbox"  /><br/>
    <input type="checkbox"  /> <br/>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Delete" id="del" />
```

and the jquery part

```
$("#del").click(function(){ 

    var length = $(":checkbox:checked").length;   //get the number of checkboxes that are checked
    var v = parseInt($("#lower").text(),10)-length;    
    $("#lower").html(v);
    $(":checkbox:checked").remove();

});
```

**here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wYdZb/4/**